# How to count the times of calling a method in a inner class?

Tags: java, twitter4j, inner-classes

```
    //get the number of tweets with keyword
public ArrayList<StreamStatus> getStream(String keyWord, int number) {
    TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();
    ArrayList<StreamStatus> list = new ArrayList<StreamStatus>();
    StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatus(Status status) {
            if(status.getGeoLocation() != null) {
                StreamStatus stramStatus = new StreamStatus();
                list.add(stramStatus);      //don't allow do that !!!
//cannot refer to a-non-final variable inside a inner class defined in a different method 
            }
        }
    };
    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    String[] keyword = {"ebola"};
    FilterQuery filtro = new FilterQuery().track(keyword);    
    twitterStream.filter(filtro);
    if(list.size() == 100) {
        twitterStream.cleanUp();
        twitterStream.shutdown();
    }
    return list;
}
```

I use other's API to implement my programming and there is a inner class in it. It seems twitterStream will use the class many times.I want to record how many times is`public void onStatus(Status status)` called?

To saying about counter, I think that is more easy to understand my problem. Actually, I just want to know how to implement `list.add(stramStatus);      //don't allow do that !!!` as I post above.

Comment: Increment a variable.

Comment: if I add a variable in inner class, how can I read it outside the inner class?

Comment: Put it somewhere else.

Comment: @cow12331 Add a getter method(or make it public).

Comment: Do I have to revise StatusListener class? Actually, I just want to use list.add() as I post above.

Comment: Does that even compile? I suspect you're getting a compilation error on the `list.add(stramStatus);` line. Please clarify what you mean by `don't allow do that !!!`.

Comment: @musical_coder cannot refer to a-non-final variable inside a inner class defined in a different method

Comment: @cow12331 So make the variable `final`. I.e., `final ArrayList<StreamStatus> list = new ArrayList<StreamStatus>();`.

Comment: See my answer below. In the future, please include a detail like that when you create the post. `don't allow do that` is vague and doesn't allow us to help you solve anything.

Comment: I thought I can not add() for final list..

Comment: No, you can. You just can't *reassign* the list using the `=` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, as the compiler is saying, that you're referring to a non-`final` variable inside an inner class. Change it to `final ArrayList<StreamStatus> list = new ArrayList<StreamStatus>();`.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
ArrayList<StreamStatus> list = new ArrayList<StreamStatus>();
```

should be declared final so you can use it.
like:

```
final List<StreamStatus> list = new ArrayList<StreamStatus>();
```

the error you get should give you a hint that you aren't allowed to access non-final stack variables.

alternatively, you can hook it up to an instance variable instead. (push the list up to the class instead of inside the method).

I have my doubts if your method will get to this:

```
twitterStream.filter(filtro);
if(list.size() == 100) {
    twitterStream.cleanUp();
    twitterStream.shutdown();
}
```

I think the list will not be exactly 100 all the time, and I you are not looping *until* it gets to there. you are risking it skips past 100 and you end up missing your cleanup/shutdown. probably you need to do:

```
while (list.size() < 100) {
    Thread.yield();
    twitterStream.filter(filtro);
}

twitterStream.cleanUp();
twitterStream.shutdown();
```

but this is just a guess as I haven't used twitterstream before and I'm only assuming the methods work as I think they do. but just keep an eye on it. ==100 is dangerous anyways in case multipel messages push it past 100 so whatever you do probably >= 100 is better even if my suggestion is completely wrong.